# Setup Cloud NAT for only 1 node pool in GKE cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-networking, gke-networking

I have a private gke cluster with multiple node pools, and reading the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example) it seems if I create a Cloud NAT its only possible to do for the whole cluster. Is there a way to configure only a subset of the cluster to have access to send traffic through the NAT? I poked around and it doesn't seem to be possible to assign a network, IP range or subnetwork to a node pool, so I am not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check [old nat gw solution](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraform-google-nat-gateway/tree/master/examples) from Google, VM instance-based instead of Cloud NAT, as an example. Possible way to do what you need is following:

1. Create dedicated [GKE node pool with tag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/node-pools/create#--tags)
2. Create NAT VM instance, using terraform examples above or manually
3. Create default route using created NAT VM instance as destination and apply this route to instances with tag you used to create GKE node pool

Referenced nat gw solution uses similar technique, but it applies route to all node pools using whole cluster tag instead of separate node pool tag.

Answer (score 0):

First we have to outline of what you will need to setup.

Components:

1.) NAT Gateway Instance

2.) Network Tags and VPC Routes

3.) Node Pools with Network Tags.

For 1 and 2,  you'd need to configure another GCE VM instance as a NAT gateway in a similar fashion as shown in our [GCE NAT tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#natgateway). This should lead to the creation of a NAT instance and a VPC route that directs network traffic from tagged resources towards the NAT.

Make sure to use tags specific to the node-pools that will be using the instance as a NAT.

For 3. In order to point the node pools to the NAT instance, you must use the correct network tags on the nodes such that traffic from these nodes are routed correctly.

Node/Nodepool with tags -> VPC Route -> NAT Instance -> Internet

In order to apply this to an entire Node Pool, you'd need to apply tags at the Node Pool level so it gets cascaded onto the underlying nodes you can see how to do it [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/node-pools/create#--tags). Unfortunately this isn't possible for existing Node Pools so you will have to delete and recreate your existing Node Pools with the corresponding tags such as below:

gcloud container node-pools create Proxy  --cluster=prod-cluster --tags=NatRouteA

Answer (score 0):

You can set up [Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview) for specific nodepool using [ip-masquerade-agent](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent).
To limit the agent to specific nodepool you need to use [node affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity) and/or [taints and tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/)